Chinese equivalent of "grow a backbone"?
What are some of your thoughts on a Chinese expression (idioms, proverbs) of telling someone to "grow a backbone"? As in that person is timid, therefore, you are telling them to be braver. Like seen in book titles like "How to Grow a Backbone: Strategies for Gaining Power and Influence At Work"... or even articles titled "How to Grow a Backbone to Say No".
To be able to express: I want you to stand up to yourself. To stand on your own feet.

Some translations I can think of are:
- 骨气（to have backbone）
 - 骨：backbone
 - 气：气势 / aura

（i.e. 有点骨气！行不行！）

- 硬气 （To be tough）
 - 硬： hardness / toughness
 - 气：气势 / aura

（i.e. 硬气点！）

- 别怂（Don't be a coward）
 - 别：don’t
 - 怂： 没意见而不愿意反抗 / to be weak and not dare to resist


Can you clarify the actual question? If you're looking for an extensive list of equivalent expressions, this falls into the Questions with too many possible answers category (see the tour page), and thus is not suitable for this site.

I never heard anyone ever say "grow some backbones" Maybe it is an American extension of the meaning of the word "spineless" which describes a weak, timid person.

"grow some backbone" seems fine to me. Possibly it's an American English thing. "grow some backbones" seems odd and wrong to me. This is borne out by two Google searches. The first estimated ~10.9 K responses, the second ~0.6 K hits.

Hello, I think I mention to say "grow a backbone". Basically a saying that tells someone to tough up. Let me edit the post a bit

But I'm still not sure what you are looking for, since I understand differently about each of your examples. The former seems to indicate  keeping tough, so that you gain the power. The latter is more like a suggestion to make a change, from never refusing anyone to saying no for the sake of yourself.
To tell someone to keep tough in a difficult situation, you can use 百折不挠/坚忍不拔/傲霜斗雪, or quote the poem 千磨万击还坚韧.
To tell someone to toughen up (from depression or failure), you can use idioms such as 重整旗鼓/卷土重来/重振雄风, or the slang 支棱起来 (video materials).

Sorry for the confusion. I should of made the examples more specific. But yes, the idioms you have mentioned are pretty great.

In addition to your examples, 挺直腰杆 (straighten your back) has a very similar meaning.
